# hi i am new to salesforce. any help will be appreciated

Tags: trigger

I need to write a trigger that calculates max and min salary from all contacts that are associated to the account and then populates the final result in account custom field min_pay__c. This is the code i have written till now but I am now stuck

trigger minpay1 on Contact (before insert) {
set acid= new set();
for(contact c: trigger.new){
acid.add(c.AccountId);
}
List result= new List();

```
result = [SELECT min(pay__c) minpayy FROM contact where id in: acid];
for(contact c:result){
    Decimal min_pay__c = (Decimal)result.get('minpayy');

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please read [ask]. This site isn't a free coding service, but rather one whose goal is to help you overcome specific (and narrowly scoped) issues to help you grow as a programmer/admin. If you've made an attempt to write this trigger of yours, you should [edit] your question to include what you've done so far (and point to a specific spot that you're stuck on). If you're getting an error message, you should also include that (the full text + stack trace, don't paraphrase it).

Comment: If you're completely new to Salesforce, https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be the better site for you to start building some knowledge and experience. This site is more "single question, authoritative answer" whereas Trailhead is more "step-by-step how to". The [Developer Beginner](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/force_com_dev_beginner) trail would be a good place to start. Learning about triggers is a part of that trail, but you need some knowledge of the SFDC platform before you jump into that.

Comment: P.S. You could use [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) for this purpose, or even read that code to learn how to build your own. Also, we have a lot of possible solutions here you can [search](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search) for.

Comment: I've linked a question that is very similar to what you're trying to do. You should be able to figure out how to do it from the top answer on that question.